# issue in installing dbus-python package on rocky linux 8.5 with python3.7.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-3.7, dbus-python

issue with installing dbus-python, is there any rpm required for it?

the rpm `python3-dbus` works well with python3.6, do we have any replacement python pakcage for python3.7.11
error:

```
Package 'glib-2.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GLIB_CFLAGS
and GLIB_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-uxwgxcuf/dbus-python/setup.py", line 111, in <module>
    tests_require=['tap.py'],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/pip-install-uxwgxcuf/dbus-python/setup.py", line 64, in run
    cwd=builddir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/pip-install-uxwgxcuf/dbus-python/configure', '--disable-maintainer-mode', 'PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3', '--prefix=/tmp/pip-install-uxwgxcuf/dbus-python/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/prefix']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-uxwgxcuf/dbus-python/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-uxwgxcuf/dbus-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-cupo0vew/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.7m/dbus-python Check the logs for full command output.